# Style "mat-sort-header-sorted" has no effect in mat-table tutorial?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to learn a bit of Angular and Material Design, and I'm having a look at the tutorial for mat-tables: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

In the example 'Table with sorting', in the CSS there is the following style definition:

```
th.mat-sort-header-sorted {
  color: black;
}
```

I really do not see what it is doing... I had assumed that the header of the sorted column would be highlighted in black, but when I tried to change it to red I didn't notice any difference.

I tried to change to 'red' both in my environment and in their StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/jxmdlyyrgka?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts

Is this some kind of bug or am I looking in the wrong direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `::ng-deep` can access class that is defined in tag as alternative to style it.

**::ng-deep** is deprecated and can be removed, also can be used

**ViewEncapsulation.None** in component decorator to avoid using ::ng-deep

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-sorted {
     color: red; /*change color of header*/
 }

 ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow {
   color: red; /*change color of arrow*/
 }
```

Comment: It works. Let me run some tests before I accept the answer

Comment: So I take it that there is something missing in their tutorial. I had never heard of this 'Encapsulation', it's still not very clear what it does. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Your welcome,here are some post about ViewEncapsulation,to get better understanding. https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-viewencapsulation-in-angular ,also there is some explanation on offical angular page.

Comment: mhm, I read your article and a bit on Angular, but I'm still confused... if 'ViewEncapsulation.Emulated' is the default value, I would assume that each of my components renders "its" style... why does it not work in this case? is this a browser problem?

Comment: ng-deep is usually used with components such Angular Material ,and cant access using regular css, ng-deep will pierce to targeted class in css.Here are also explanation on offical page https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: Using `::ng-deep` works perfectly. Very odd that you can't style `.mat-sort-header-sorted` directly with your own styles loading on your browser - I would think that this is a bug and not a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Please define custom CSS styles as follows:

```css
.text-underline {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.text-bold {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

.color-black {
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<th class="text-underline text-bold color-black" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> value </th>
```

Comment: I'll try to have a look at it if I find my project again ;) thank you anyway!

Comment: This only applies to the `th` not the `button` element which the text is actually nested inside. This solution will only work if your text doesn't overflow into multiple rows of text within the cell. If it does, you need to use the solution with `::ng-deep`